When I try to deploy my smart contract with ganache and try yo conect to the virtual blockchain, this message pop up in the terminal of visual studio
When I try to deploy my smart contract with ganache and try yo conect to the virtual blockchain, this message pop up in the terminal of visual studio. Why?
I hope somebody give my a response please. I'm lost it.
Deploying, Please wait...
JsonRpcProvider failed to detect network and cannot start up; retry in 1s (perhaps the URL is wrong or the node is not started)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:7545
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '0.0.0.0',
port: 7545
}

I've never seen anyone use the IP address 0.0.0.0. Probably you meant to use localhost 127.0.0.1.
Also check that the port is the correct one. Unless you changed it, the default should be 8545.
Lastly, wait some seconds between launching ganache and using it as provider.
